# Download package with npm install command from local API

Tags: node.js, express, npm

**Context:**

I encountered an unusual issue (for me) as a junior web developer. My organization wanted to manage local package tarballs within specific folders for better control over the packages we install. To address this, I considered creating an API.

**The code:**

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 3000;
const fs = require('fs');

app.get('/tarballs/:packageName', (req, res) => {
    
    const { packageName } = req.params;
    const tarballPath = `./packages/${packageName}.tgz`;

    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/octet-stream');
    res.setHeader('Content-Disposition', `attachment; filename=${packageName}.tgz`);
    
    const readStream = fs.createReadStream(tarballPath);
    readStream.pipe(res);
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`API running on port ${port}`);
});
```

I also modified the npm registry like this:

```bash
npm set registry http://localhost:3000/tarballs/
```

**The problem:**

When I access this URL in my browser: `http://localhost:3000/tarballs/my-package`, it downloads the tgz file successfully.

When I execute `npm i http://localhost:3000/tarballs/my-package`, it works as expected.

However, when I attempt `npm i my-package`, I encounter the following error:

```less
npm ERR! Invalid JSON response body http://localhost:3000/tarballs/my-package reason: Unexpected token in JSON at position 0
```

I'm curious why providing the direct URL works, but using only the package name doesn't. Is there a solution to this problem? I considered using `app.use()` instead of conventional routes, but that might cause issues if someone tries `npm i my-package.tgz`, as it would search within the project repository instead of the API.

If there's no fix for this approach, is there a guide available for setting up a custom package server (not relying on existing solutions like Verdaccio)? My boss prefers a homemade solution.

Thanks, and have a great day!